# Clarification regarding Dilworth Theorem Proof

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

This is the proof I am talking about.

http://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/F03/Class14.pdf

It is given that : 
P⁻∩ P⁺=A 
Otherwise there exists x,i, j such that ai < x < aj and so A is not an
anti-chain.

Please could anybody explain this to me ?  Why should the intersection of P⁻ and P⁺ be equal to A ?

Comment: Can you explain what $P^\pm$, $A$ etc. are without having to refer us to this pdf?

Comment: A is an antichain A = {a1, a2, . . . , am} in P \ C. C is a maximal chain  in the poset P .  P⁺ = {x ∈ P : x ≤ ai for some i}. P⁻ =  {x ∈ P : x ≥ ai for some i}.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A$ is obviously included in $P^-$ and in $P^+$, we have $A\subseteq P^-\cap P^+$. The problem is to prove the reverse inclusion.  So consider any element $x\in P^-\cap P^+$; I need to show that $x\in A$. By definition of $P^-$ there is an $i$ such that $x\leq a_i$. If $x=a_i$, that means $x\in A$, so I'm done. It remains to consider the situation when $x<a_i$. Similarly, by definition of $P^+$, $x\geq a_j$ for some $j$, and I'm done if equality holds, so I need only consider the situation when $x>a_j$.  But then $a_j<x<a_i$, which means that two different elements of $A$ are comparable: $a_j<a_i$. That contradicts the fact that $A$ is an antichain.